# Appendix (with quoted literature) after bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, appendix

I have the following question (also [asked in German on goLaTeX](https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=24690)): My thesis is structured like this:

Chapter 1
chapter 2
Chapter 3

Complete bibliography

Appendix
Chapter A
Chapter B

My problem: In my appendix I cite literature that I already cite in chapters 1-3. When this happens, the full title is shown to me again in the appendix and not the short title (it occurs usually when I cite a book the second time) - how can I make it so that the short title is shown to me in the appendix if I already cite the book in the chapters before the overall bibliography?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,citepages=separate,backend=biber,sblfootnotes=false,ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,sorting=nyvt,url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,uniquename=false]{biblatex} 


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Engelmann:2013,
  author      = {Engelmann, Hans},
  title       = {Die Sicht. Mit einem Vorwort von Bill Wright zur Sicht},
  location    = {Berlin},
  date        = {2013},
  series      = {Gamma Omega, I. Reihe: Alpha},
  shortseries = {GO.A},
  number      = {4},
  }

@book{Ab.2005,
 author = {Wright, Bill},
 gender = {sm}, 
  date = {1966},
 title = {A short history},
location = {Amsterdam},
keywords = {Hilfsmittel},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

Erstes Mal zitiert.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}
Zweites Mal zitiert - es folgt der Kurztitel (ohne Reihe, Druckort und Jahr).\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}
\printbibliography
\part{Anhang}
Drittes Mal zitiert - aber hier werden die Bücher wieder komplett zitiert-  wie erhalte ich hier den Kurztitel?\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}
Viertes Mal zitiert - es folgt der Kurztitel (ohne Reihe, Druckort und Jahr).\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How have you defined your short titles? What is the output you would like, your `bib` entries do not appear to have short titles defined in them, do you have them defined in your main `bib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-sbl` has an explicit `\citereset` in `\AtBeginBibliography` ([ll. 5-19 in `sbl.bbx`](https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/blob/77f208b1129d8024cff4de6fcb71b763c258ec31/latex/sbl.bbx#L5-L19)). Effectively that means that `\printbibliography` resets all citation tracking, in particular also the long/short tracker. So you get long citations (as if the entry had not been cited before) after the bibliography.

Because the `\AtBeginBibliography` comes from the style, it is pretty tricky to get rid of its effect. One option would be to locally redefine `\citereset` to do nothing in a group around `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=sbl,
  sorting=nyvt,
  uniquename=false,
  citepages=separate,
  sblfootnotes=false,
  ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,
  url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,
]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Engelmann:2013,
  author      = {Engelmann, Hans},
  title       = {Die Sicht. Mit einem Vorwort von Bill Wright zur Sicht},
  location    = {Berlin},
  date        = {2013},
  series      = {Gamma Omega, I. Reihe: Alpha},
  shortseries = {GO.A},
  number      = {4},
}
@book{Ab.2005,
  author   = {Wright, Bill},
  gender   = {sm}, 
  date     = {1966},
  title    = {A short history},
  location = {Amsterdam},
  keywords = {Hilfsmittel},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem.\footcites[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}[Siehe auch:][]{Ab.2005}
Ipsum.\footcites[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}[Siehe auch:][]{Ab.2005}

{\def\citereset{}
\printbibliography}
\part{Anhang}
Dolor.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}
Sit.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}

\end{document}
```

[image: 3 Vgl. Engelmann, Die Sicht. Mit einem Vorwort von Bill Wright zur Sicht, 1. Siehe auch: Wright, A short history. 4 Vgl. Engelmann, Die Sicht. Mit einem Vorwort von Bill Wright zur Sicht, 1. Siehe auch: Wright, A short history.]

There is a danger that this change might cause issues in the bibliography. After all, the `\citereset` was added there by the style developer for a reason. This is relevant if the bibliography style makes use of (internal) citation commands or citation tracking features.

---

A slightly more complex, but potentially less invasive method could save and restore the tracker state of only the "if cite seen" tracker before and after the `\printbibliography` like this

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=sbl,
  sorting=nyvt,
  uniquename=false,
  citepages=separate,
  sblfootnotes=false,
  ibidpage=true,ibidtracker=true,idemtracker=true,pagetracker=spread,
  url=false,isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\saveseenstate}{%
  \csletcs{saved@blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}%
  \csletcs{saved@blx@fsee@\the\c@refsection}{blx@fsee@\the\c@refsection}}
\newcommand*{\restoreseenstate}{%
  \csletcs{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{saved@blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}%
  \csletcs{blx@fsee@\the\c@refsection}{saved@blx@fsee@\the\c@refsection}}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Engelmann:2013,
  author      = {Engelmann, Hans},
  title       = {Die Sicht. Mit einem Vorwort von Bill Wright zur Sicht},
  location    = {Berlin},
  date        = {2013},
  series      = {Gamma Omega, I. Reihe: Alpha},
  shortseries = {GO.A},
  number      = {4},
}
@book{Ab.2005,
  author   = {Wright, Bill},
  gender   = {sm}, 
  date     = {1966},
  title    = {A short history},
  location = {Amsterdam},
  keywords = {Hilfsmittel},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem.\footcites[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}[Siehe auch:][]{Ab.2005}
Ipsum.\footcites[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}[Siehe auch:][]{Ab.2005}

\saveseenstate
\printbibliography
\restoreseenstate

\part{Anhang}
Dolor.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}
Sit.\footnote{\cite[Vgl.][1]{Engelmann:2013}. Siehe auch: \cite{Ab.2005}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for both answers. Unfortunately, both solutions does not show the expected result in my file. Thus, I have used your solution as a base and put all my other commands in a new file - and it works. However, when I put your solutions in my 'real' file nothing changed; I have deleted all my aux-, etc.- files, but there is no change. In the log-files, there was no information, too. What I can do in such a case? Is there another solution maybe?

Comment: @test If this is on Overleaf, make sure that all your project use the newest TeX Live version. If it isn't (or if you already use the same version everywhere) I'm afraid, you'll have to try and isolate the code in your document that stops this solution from working. Unfortunately, there are many, many different things that could be problematic here and we have no idea what your document looks like.

Comment: thanks again. Indeed, the 'new' file was in overleaf and my 'real' file in TeXniccenter. I have updated now my version and it worked in my 'real' file when I used my complete code with a small part of my work (even with \include!); but when I add a larger number of my \include chapters to it, it does not recognize the citation from the part before the bibliography.

Comment: @test Check how many `\include`s you need (and if it really is the number of `\include`s you have or specific contents of the `\include`d files). Do this to generate a minimal example document that exhibits the issue. Then share it with us.

Comment: Thank you again! I have gone through all elements step by step and I got my fault: I have overlooked "\printbiblist" - it has to be surronded with "\def\citereset{}" or rather "saveseenstate - restoreseenstate", too! I am happy that it worked out now; thanks again!